# Retrieve output of alias function in r

Tags: r

Before running a model I am running a alias function to check multicollinearity.
My code is:

```
    >ss<-lm(final_res~.,data = dev1)
        >summary(ss)
    Output:
        Call:
        lm(formula = final_res ~ ., data = dev1)

        Residuals:
             Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
        -0.32213 -0.02461 -0.01624 -0.00899  1.00588 

        Coefficients: (5 not defined because of singularities)
                                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
        (Intercept)                             6.226e-02  6.156e-03  10.113  < 2e-16 ***
        avg_dp_6month                           1.344e-06  3.866e-06   0.348  0.72808    
        dp_increase                             6.861e-03  6.973e-03   0.984  0.32519    
        dp_decrease                            -9.699e-03  1.222e-02  -0.794  0.42723    
        GrossMarginCR60                         1.188e-03  3.005e-04   3.953 7.72e-05 ***
        ClientCity                             -4.589e-06  8.414e-06  -0.545  0.58544    
        Gender                                 -3.789e-03  8.908e-04  -4.254 2.10e-05 ***
        ClientSubcategory                      -5.518e-03  1.399e-03  -3.943 8.04e-05 ***
        FinalSegment                            1.257e-02  1.485e-03   8.464  < 2e-16 ***
        mob_201512                             -6.363e-05  9.237e-06  -6.889 5.68e-12 ***
        age_201512                             -4.555e-04  3.603e-05 -12.641  < 2e-16 ***
        wm_channel_flag                        -2.006e-02  7.122e-03  -2.816  0.00486 ** 
        broking_activity_indicator              3.010e-03  7.209e-04   4.176 2.97e-05 ***
        dp_status_flag                          1.257e-02  3.130e-03   4.015 5.94e-05 ***
        non_mf_tran_avg_6month                 -1.773e-03  3.170e-04  -5.592 2.25e-08 ***
        non_mf_delivery_trade_avg_6month        1.866e-04  8.196e-05   2.276  0.02284 *  
        non_mf_trading_trade_avg_6month                NA         NA      NA       NA    
        non_mf_buy_tran_avg_6month              4.153e-03  6.389e-04   6.501 8.04e-11 ***
        non_mf_sell_tran_avg_6month                    NA         NA      NA       NA    
        non_mf_revenue_avg_6month              -2.727e-07  8.693e-08  -3.136  0.00171 ** 
        non_mf_quantity_avg_6month             -2.143e-09  3.622e-09  -0.592  0.55410    
        non_mf_volume_avg_6month                2.585e-11  1.530e-11   1.689  0.09123 .  
        non_mf_normal_terminal_avg_6month       4.665e-03  2.662e-03   1.752  0.07973 .  
        non_mf_exe_offline_terminal_avg_6month         NA         NA      NA       NA    
        switcher_flag                           5.557e-03  2.693e-03   2.064  0.03905 *  
        only_mf_flag                                   NA         NA      NA       NA    
        only_non_mf_flag                       -4.302e-02  3.669e-03 -11.726  < 2e-16 ***
        only_mf_and_non_mf_flag                        NA         NA      NA       NA    
        ---
        Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

        Residual standard error: 0.1348 on 76943 degrees of freedom
          (1427 observations deleted due to missingness)
        Multiple R-squared:  0.01321,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01293 
        F-statistic: 46.84 on 22 and 76943 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> alias(ss)
Model :
final_res ~ avg_dp_6month + dp_increase + dp_decrease + GrossMarginCR60 + 
    ClientCity + Gender + ClientSubcategory + FinalSegment + 
    mob_201512 + age_201512 + wm_channel_flag + broking_activity_indicator + 
    dp_status_flag + non_mf_tran_avg_6month + non_mf_delivery_trade_avg_6month + 
    non_mf_trading_trade_avg_6month + non_mf_buy_tran_avg_6month + 
    non_mf_sell_tran_avg_6month + non_mf_revenue_avg_6month + 
    non_mf_quantity_avg_6month + non_mf_volume_avg_6month + non_mf_normal_terminal_avg_6month + 
    non_mf_exe_offline_terminal_avg_6month + switcher_flag + 
    only_mf_flag + only_non_mf_flag + only_mf_and_non_mf_flag

Complete :
                                       (Intercept) avg_dp_6month dp_increase dp_decrease GrossMarginCR60 ClientCity Gender ClientSubcategory FinalSegment mob_201512
non_mf_trading_trade_avg_6month         0           0             0           0           0               0          0      0                 0            0        
non_mf_sell_tran_avg_6month             0           0             0           0           0               0          0      0                 0            0        
non_mf_exe_offline_terminal_avg_6month  0           0             0           0           0               0          0      0                 0            0        
only_mf_flag                            0           0             0           0           0               0          0      0                 0            0        
only_mf_and_non_mf_flag                 1           0             0           0           0               0          0      0                 0            0        
                                       age_201512 wm_channel_flag broking_activity_indicator dp_status_flag non_mf_tran_avg_6month non_mf_delivery_trade_avg_6month
non_mf_trading_trade_avg_6month         0          0               0                          0              1                     -1                              
non_mf_sell_tran_avg_6month             0          0               0                          0              1                      0                              
non_mf_exe_offline_terminal_avg_6month  0          0               0                          0              1                      0                              
only_mf_flag                            0          0               0                          0              0                      0                              
only_mf_and_non_mf_flag                 0          0               0                          0              0                      0                              
                                       non_mf_buy_tran_avg_6month non_mf_revenue_avg_6month non_mf_quantity_avg_6month non_mf_volume_avg_6month
non_mf_trading_trade_avg_6month         0                          0                         0                          0                      
non_mf_sell_tran_avg_6month            -1                          0                         0                          0                      
non_mf_exe_offline_terminal_avg_6month  0                          0                         0                          0                      
only_mf_flag                            0                          0                         0                          0                      
only_mf_and_non_mf_flag                 0                          0                         0                          0                      
                                       non_mf_normal_terminal_avg_6month switcher_flag only_non_mf_flag
non_mf_trading_trade_avg_6month         0                                 0             0              
non_mf_sell_tran_avg_6month             0                                 0             0              
non_mf_exe_offline_terminal_avg_6month -1                                 0             0              
only_mf_flag                            0                                 0             0              
only_mf_and_non_mf_flag                 0                                 0            -1
```

How to save the alias output (the complete section) in a dataframe?
I have tried with tidy(from broom library).I have used it previously to store model summary as dataframe. But it is not working in here. So any suggestion or idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list returned by `alias` only has two or three elements, one of them being `Complete`. Slight modification of the example in `?alias` to check that it works with `lm`-objects as well as `aov` one (although the help page clearly says it should:

```
> op <- options(contrasts = c("contr.helmert", "contr.poly"))
> lm.mod <- lm(yield ~ block + N*P*K, npk)
> alias(lm.mod)$Complete
         (Intercept) block1 block2 block3 block4 block5 N1    P1    K1    N1:P1
N1:P1:K1     0           1    1/3    1/6  -3/10   -1/5      0     0     0     0
         N1:K1 P1:K1
N1:P1:K1     0     0
> as.data.frame(alias(lm.mod)$Complete)
         (Intercept) block1    block2    block3 block4 block5 N1 P1 K1 N1:P1
N1:P1:K1           0      1 0.3333333 0.1666667   -0.3   -0.2  0  0  0     0
         N1:K1 P1:K1
N1:P1:K1     0     0
```

Comment: Sir...Thanks for the solution...I am actually building Shiny apps for modelling..thanks again..

Comment: Then that is a separate question.